# I can't set a permanent path in Java

Tags: java, cmd, javac

I recently created my very first Java file and tried to compile it in cmd, but whenever I do so, I have to set the specific path to the file. After setting the right path to the file, javac works properly. However, this is very annoying and time-consuming for me. I did some research about it and I presume that if I set a permanent path in the 'system variables', then I will never have to set the same path again.

However, even after I set the path of the file's location (the location is correct) in the system variables, javac still returns *"file not found".*

Comment: What do you mean by *"set the specific path to the file"?* Can you show an example? You must specify where the file is to `javac`, there's no way around that. However, you can change your directory to the directory where your file is. Then you just need to type the name of the file.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I was about to ask the same question.

Comment: @Jack, Forget about Java. Imagine you are the compiler and I'm you. I tell you "Jack, compile HelloWorld.java". Now tell me, how in the hell are you gonna know where the file is located? What if there are multiple "HelloWorld.java" files scattered all over the file system. How are you going to know which one I need to compile if I don't tell you where to find it?  When you're working on an IDE, all of the paths are resolved relative to the project top folder. AND EVEN THEN, when you compile an application, there is little "trickery" the IDE does behind the scenes to figure out file locations.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman For example, when the file is located on my Desktop, I have to type "cd Desktop" in cmd every time I compile. Typing "cd Desktop" is annoying already, but I guess most of the Java files are in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin" and there's no way I'm typing that in (or copy and paste) every time I compile something...

Comment: @hfontanez So you mean I have to specify the location of the file every time I compile? I thought if I set the permanent path such as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin", the file inside the permanent path will be compiled even without having me set the "temporary path".

Comment: @Jack Yes, you **must** specify the path to all files. You should **not** add your sources to the system PATH variable. That is only for command line executables, such as programs as `cd` or `javac`. More often than not, you'll use a build script or build system though. There are many different available and they're often bundled together with an IDE (Integrated Development Environment, i.e. a flashy text editor with some development tools). My suggestion is to download a proper IDE like [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/).

Comment: @Jack My answer is what Ted Klein Bergman posted. I would like to add to his answer that an IDE is more than a collection of integrated tools used for software development. It's also a tool that document dependencies needed at compile time as well as runtime. That includes the location of source and compiled resources, the location of the Java "home" folder, etc. Many of these are left at default values. BUT, if you explore your settings, you'll find all of these things explicitly set. When you DON'T use an IDE, you must, as Ted mentioned, specify all these paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javac` **cannot** do what you want, not with 'system variables' as you describe. But this isn't a problem java programmers normally run into:

1. If you really want to compile on the command line with a shell, ooookay, that's not the normal way to do it (that's to use smart editors and build systems), but.. just have a terminal open, in the right  directory (the one containing 'YourApp.java'), and you can just type `javac YourApp.java`, and that will work.
2. If your project is more complicated and you insist on `javac` on the command line, make a shell script.
3. More usually, you have a smart editor, such as Eclipse or Intellij. Even if you don't, most 'dumb' editors still have a menu option to run a command on the current file. Add an entry for `javac` and voila, you're now 1 key combo away from compiling the code.

Comment: "not with 'system variables' as you describe" - I think Jack is confused with setting `JAVA_HOME` and the location of the .java files

Comment: @hfontanez Yes, I am. Whenever I search about setting a path of a file, the solution says something about setting JAVA_HOME, but I have no idea what JAVA_HOME is...

Comment: @Jack `JAVA_HOME` is an environment variable you set to the path to the Java executable so that tools that uses Java knows where to find it. It will not solve your current problem, but might solve other problems down the line.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Apparently, the textbook I'm using to learn Java wants me to use JDK command-line tool, but I don't know how to download it... I can only see the JRE folder when I download JDK...

Comment: @Jack Search the web for "OpenJDK download".

Comment: Um, I guess downloading Eclipse was the answer. THANK YOU to everybody who helped me to solve this problem! I really appreciate your attention and help! Thank you again and have a nice day!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you **must** specify the path to all files. However, there are things that might make it easier for you. For example, `javac` takes wildcards, so after moving to the directory with all your source files, you can run `javac *.java` to compile them. This isn't applied recursively to subfolders though. But the more proper solutions are:

### Use a build system.

Build systems are made to make it easier and faster to build your application. This is what a wast majority of developers use. There are many different ones, but the most common are [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/what_is_gradle.html), [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) and [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/). There are also build systems included in many IDE's (Integrated Development Environment, i.e. a flashy text editor with some development tools) such as [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/). It's **highly recommended** to use an IDE when developing.

### Write a build system yourself

Simple build systems doesn't have to be complicated. The most stupidly simple solution is to just take all the commands you have to put in to the terminal in order to build your application, and put them in a batch/shell script. This is different depending on which operating system you're using, but here are some examples:

**MacOS/Linux**, save as `build.sh`.

```
cd /Users/you/Programming/MyProject
javac Main.java File1.java File2.java
java Main
```

**Windows**, save as `build.bat`.

```
cd C:\Documents\Programming\MyProject
javac Main.java File1.java File2.java
java Main
```

Then you can just run them to compile with `./build.sh` or `build.bat`.

If you're on MacOS/Linux, you might have to change the permissions of the file using `chmod +x build.sh`.